# How to populate a particular column list in Combo Box with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, html, drop-down-menu

I am using the given code below to populate some values from a column of a table. It's just getting filled blank..

Can you please find the problem with it ?

```
<select name="category">
    <option value="" selected>Select a category</option>
    <?php
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("muskilaasaan");
        $category = "SELECT cat FROM category";
        $query_result = mysql_query($category);
        while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
        {
        ?>
            <option value = "<?php echo $result['cat']?>"/>
        <?php
        }

    ?>  
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name="category">
    <option value="" selected>Select a category</option>
    <?php
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("muskilaasaan");
        $category = "SELECT cat FROM category";
        $query_result = mysql_query($category);
        while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result))
        {
        ?>
            <option value = "<?php echo $result['cat']?>"><?php echo $result['cat']?></option>
        <?php
        }

    ?>  
</select>
```

Changed to mysql_fetch_assoc and also you didn't put anything in the option tags, that would cause it to appear blank.

Comment: @RajeevKumar How about a green check. :)

Answer (score 0):

it does not help if you specify the connection string as a second argument in mysql_select_db() ? see here for an example: http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-select-db.php

Comment: I have tried to print the value on the page and it worked nicely..

I am getting problem with populating those values in combo box..

Comment: try this:
    <?php
        $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("muskilaasaan",$conn);
        $category = "SELECT cat FROM category";
        $query_result = mysql_query($category);
        while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
        {
           echo "<option value ='".$result['cat']."'>".$result['cat']."</option>";
        
        }

    ?>  
</select>